# Conversion base 11 to decimal

Tags: c++, radix

I know that the `unsigned long` is up to 4294967295 only, so here's my problem, when the user inputs many numbers (like the result is going to exceed on the limit) the converted number will be just 4294967295.
example:

```
Base 11: 1928374192847
Decimal: 4294967295
```

the result should be 5777758712535. how to fix this limit ? vb6.0 required to us.
here's my code:

```
    cout << "\t\t  CONVERSION\n";
    cout << "\t     Base 11 to Decimal\n";
    cout << "\nBase 11: ";
    cin >> str;
    const auto x = str.find_first_not_of("0123456789aA");
    if (x != string::npos)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid Input\n\n";
        goto a;
    }
    unsigned long x = strtoul(str.c_str(), NULL, 11);
    cout << "Decimal: " << x << "\n\n";
```

The program should say "out of range" if the result will exceed 4294967295.
Sorry im just a beginner.

Comment: [std::strtoul](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtoul) will let you know if there was a range error.

Comment: ***vb6.0 required to us*** I think you mean Visual C++ 6.0. The code is not Visual Basic.

Comment: @drescherjm fortunately the code is compatible.

Comment: No. Visual Basic is a totally different language.

Answer (score 2):

From the [strtoul docs on www.cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtoul/) :

> If the value read is out of the range of representable values by an unsigned long int, the function returns ULONG_MAX (defined in <climits>), and errno is set to ERANGE.

You should check the errno to determine if the value was out of range.